# show popup for a particular time after that popup close automatically

Tags: javascript

Below i mentioned my page contents
Currently it'l show only popup box for a sec only ,but i need to extend the time  ihave no idea how to do that

**script i used**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
        e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        lightbox_close();
    }
}
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

**my button**

```
<input type="submit"    value="SUBMIT" onclick="lightbox_open();"  />
```

**poup  box**

```
<div id="light">
    <a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
    <h3 th:text="${result}"></h3>
    hi hello
</div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Window setTimeout() method for this purpose.

```
var t=setTimeout(lightbox_close,3000)
```

Comment: where can i add this line on my current script?

Comment: Inside the lightbox_open function, because you need to call the function only after opening the lightbox

Comment: actually the page is redirecting to another page ,is there that ok?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) event. If you are using jQuery for example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#element').hide();

  window.setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#element').show(); 
  }, 5000);

});
```

You can swap the hide/show around to suit your needs.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfCHG/1/

Comment: can i add this to above script?

Comment: Yeah put the setTimeout at the bottom of your `lightbox_open` function

Comment: what is the #element supposed to be?

Comment: actually the page is redirecting to another page ,is there that ok?